# VS 2010 Markup Formatting For Comments

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to format

```
...
</div>
<%--Parent Category--%>
<div class="field">
...
```

to

```
...
</div>

<%--Parent Category--%>

<div class="field">
...
```

I could not find a way to do that using Tag Specific Options in Tools-->Options. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

Go to the Tag Specific Options, add a new Tag to the `Client HTML Tags`. 
The name of the tag should be `%--` 
Closing tag: No Closing Tag 
Link breaks: 2 Before opening, within, and 2 after closing

This will format it the way you want, and it will not touch the `<%:` and `<%=` directives, for which you also could define formatting by adding tag for them and calling them `%=` and `%:`